# Error en arreglo de Java ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

Buenas, estoy aprendiendo a programar en Java y al ejecutar el código:

```
package useargumeny;

public class UseArgumeny {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Hi, ");
        System.out.print(args[0]);
        System.out.print(".how are you");
    }
}
```

El compilador me arroja el siguiente

> error:package useargumeny:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>   Hi,     at useargumeny.UseArgumeny.main(UseArgumeny.java:7)
>   C:\Users\probook\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Hola David, es mas fácil de leer si dejamos el texto en lugar de la imagen.

Comment: Adicional a las respuestas que ya tienes. El problema es que tu programa en Java no recibe argumentos. Solución: pasarle argumentos. Dado que trabajas en NetBeans, puedes ver cómo pasar argumentos a tu programa. [Acá hay un ejemplo](http://javadhc.blogspot.pe/2012/12/pasar-argumentos-al-programa-en-netbeans.html). Ten en cuenta que si ejecutas este código en otro IDE, deberás buscar la manera de pasar los argumentos en ese IDE, o sino ejecutar el programa desde una consola (como se explica en otras respuestas).

Comment: me pasa exactamente el mismo error C:\Users\probook\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED .. que estara pasando con esto , ya llevo 2 semanas sin poder avanzar con este NETBEANS..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu tienes aqui `args[0]` algo llamado [Arreglo](http://aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=168:repaso-arrays-o-arreglos-unidimensionales-en-java-tipos-de-inicializacion-ejemplos-de-codigo-cu00902c&catid=58:curso-lenguaje-programacion-java-nivel-avanzado-i&Itemid=180) que es mas o menos una secuencia de datos de mismo tipo accesables por un indice. Y aparte `args` es un Arreglo especial de los programas en java donde se pueden pasar parametros desde otro lugar.

Lo que sucede aqui es que cuando ejecutas tu codigo desde un IDE (netbeans en tu caso) No se manda ningun argumento a tu programa y por eso muestra la excepción `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` que indica que le estas pidiendo un elemento no contenido en tu arreglo

Una analogia del mundo real seria:

> Tu madre te manda a comprar cosas al super, cuando regresas a casa te pide el cambio, pero tu gastaste todo el dinero, asi que dices **no te lo puedo dar** en ves de simplemente darle el cambio.

Para ejecutar tu programa abre una consola, y colocate en tu carpeta donde se genera tu archivo `.class` y escribe

```
java UseArgumeny David
```

Esto hara funcionar a medias tu programa, ya que ahora recibe un argumento, y sin problema lo muestra.

Para solventar el caso de que no te manden argumentos utiliza una sentencia `if`

```
System.out.print("Hi, ");
if(args.length > 0){
    System.out.print(args[0]);
}
System.out.print(".how are you");
```

Answer (score 1):

Es por que no estas validando si el array `args` tiene elementos. Tu programa **No** fallará si agregas un argumento de linea de comando, cuando lo ejecutas:

```
$ java UseArgumeny.class rnrneverdies
Hi, rnrneverdies.how are you
```

Para resolverlo debes validar si hay argumentos utilizando `args.length` de alguna forma y si no los hay, por ejemplo, puedes dar otro mensaje o lo que necesites.

```
package useargumeny;

public class UseArgumeny {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            System.out.print("Hola, ");
            System.out.print(args[0]);
            System.out.print(" ¿Como estas?");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Quien eres tu?");
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder. Sin embargo ahora aparece lo siguiente: run:
Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal useargumeny.UseArgumeny
C:\Users\probook\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente el arreglo args no tiene valor para obtener `args[0]`:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
            ...
            System.out.print(args[0]);
            ...           
        }
```

tendrias que validar este caso.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
            ...
            if (args.length > 0) {
            System.out.print(args[0]);
            }else{
            System.out.print("args esta vació!");
            } 
            ...           
        }
```