# ¿Como soluciono este error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11"?

Tags: java

El programa se trata de crear un vector aleatorio, mostrarlo y ordenarlo por el método de ordenamiento burbuja, por lo tanto hice un menú donde el crear vector, mostrarlo y ordenarlo esta en distintas funciones. Pero al intentar llamar la función de burbuja sale el siguiente error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11"

```
static int[] crearvector ()  throws IOException
{
Random a=new Random();
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
int e,numero,m,q,aux,j;
System.out.println("Digite el tamaño del vector:");          //Creación del vector
m=in.nextInt();
int vector[]=new int[m+1];
System.out.println("Creando vector Random...");
for (e=0;e<m;e++)
{
    numero=a.nextInt(5);
    vector[e]=numero;    
}
    return vector;
}
```

El siguiente codigo es el ordenamiento burbuja

```
    static int [] burbuja (int a[]) throws IOException
{
    int q,aux,j,e;

    for (q=0;q<a.length;q++)
        for (j=0;j<a.length;j++)
            {
                if(a[j]>a[j+1])
                    {
                        aux=a[j];
                        a[j]=a[j+1];        //Metodo de ordenamiento Burbuja
                        a[j+1]=aux;
                    }
            }

    for (e=0;e<a.length;e++)
        System.out.print(a[e]);



    return a;
}
```

El siguiente código es el menú

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] j = null;
    //int[] l=null;
    int opcion;
    do
    {
        System.out.println ("\n\n MENU PRINCIPAL DE OPCIONES ");
        System.out.println ("\n1.Crear vector");
        System.out.println ("2.Mostrar vector");
        System.out.println ("3.Media");
        System.out.println ("4.Mediana");
        System.out.println ("0.Salir del Programa. ");
        System.out.print (" Seleccione Opcion: ");
         opcion = in.nextInt();
         switch (opcion)
         {
          case 1: 
                    j=crearvector();
                    System.out.println("Vector Creado");
                  break;
           case 2: mostrarvector(j);
                  break;
           case 3:media(j);
                  break;
           case 4:burbuja(j); 
                  //mediana(l);
                  break;
           case 0: System.out.println("\n\nFin.\n");
                  break;
           default: System.out.println("\nOpcion Invalida!");
          }
    }while(opcion!=0);
}
```

}

Y el siguiente es el error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11
at vector.Vector.burbuja(Vector.java:53)
at vector.Vector.main(Vector.java:143)
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error en arreglo de Java ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3344/error-en-arreglo-de-java-arrayindexoutofboundsexception)

Answer (score 2):

El error `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` es lanzado cuando se intenta acceder a una posición fuera de los límites del arreglo. En este caso basta con restarle uno a la condición de parada del segundo `for` en el método `burbuja()`.

```
static int[] burbuja(int a[]) throws IOException {
    int q, aux, j, e;

    for (q = 0; q < a.length; q++) {
        for (j = 0; j < a.length - 1; j++) {      //Aquí estaba el error
            if (a[j] > a[j + 1]) {
                aux = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j + 1];        //Metodo de ordenamiento Burbuja
                a[j + 1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
    for (e = 0; e < a.length; e++) {
        System.out.print(a[e]);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Como dato extra, cuando digítas el tamaño del vector e intentas crearlo, lo que estás haciendo es crear un vector con la cantidad digitada mas 1. Por tanto, si ingresas 4, tendrás 5 elementos en el vector.

```
System.out.println("Digite el tamaño del vector:");          //Creación del vector
m=in.nextInt();
int vector[]=new int[m];       //Arreglado
```